# Acción de botón en UITableViewCell con Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Estoy tratando de hacer una tabla con celdas personalizadas en swift hasta ahi va bien, pero decidí meterle un botón de `me gusta` a cada celda, el botón al ser presionado simplemente cambia su imagen, entonces el problema que tengo es que: Cada que presiono el botón `me gusta` si cambia el la imagen del botón pero la cambia para la celda en la que se cuentrá el botón presionado y para otras de la misma lista tal y como lo muestra la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que sucede en la imagen es que presiono el botón de arriba pero cambia también el botón de hasta abajo (por decir un ejemplo), estoy tratando de reutilizar la misma celda con `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` este es mi código:

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DestinoTableViewCell
        cell.btnCorazon.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnCorazon.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changueButon), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       print("select", indexPath.row)
    }

    func changueButon(sender: UIButton){

        if(!self.isLove){
            if let image = UIImage(named: "heart.png") {
                sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

                isLove = true
            }
        }else{
            if let image = UIImage(named: "fav.png") {
                sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                isLove = false
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Entonces mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar este problema? y si la hay ¿cual es?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías adjuntar la imagen de nuevo? No se ve. En cuanto al código que adjuntas no está bien. Deberías tener implementado un delegado en la celda para que cuando pulses sobre el botón se active la acción que quieres.

Comment: segun yo si se mira la img, y como le agrego el delegado a ala celda? ya que casi todos los tutos que e visto lo hacen asi pero no señalan ese problema

Comment: Gracias, ahora si he podido verla. Te adjunto código ejemplo para que agregues un delegado a la celda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `DestinoTableViewCell` créate un protocol de la siguiente forma:

```
protocol DestinoTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func didPressHeartButton(sender: UIButton)
}
```

Posteriormente, en tu clase declaras una propiedad de tipo weak que es el delegado. Esto se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
weak var delegate: DestinoTableViewCellDelegate?
```

Una vez tengas esto, hay que utilizar el delegado. Para ello, una vez pulses el botón, dentro del selector, haciendo la llamada dentro de la clase de la celda, haces lo siguiente:

```
func changueButon(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didPressHeartButton(sender: sender)
}
```

**Es importante que la acción del botón de la celda la implementes dentro de la clase de la celda.**

Por último, en tu `ViewController`, dentro del método `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, asignas el delegado e implementas el método del delegado extendiendo el ViewController.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DestinoTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

extension ViewController: DestinoTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didPressHeartButton(sender: UIButton) {
        // Implementas tu código y la acción que desees realizar con el botón.
    }
}
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: cuando agrego `weak var delegate: DestinoTableViewCellDelegate` en mi clase me pide que lo ponga opcional `weak var delegate: DestinoTableViewCellDelegate?` entonces cuando ejecuto el click no entra en la accion del protocolo `didPressHeartButton `

Comment: Comprueba que has asignado a la celda (cell.delegate = self) y que dentro de la clase de la celda está implementada la acción del botón. En caso de ser una imagen, activa el userInteractionEnabled = true.

Comment: bien el click funciona el problema es que me sigue haciendo lo mismo, al presionar un boton del item 1 de la tabla, al dar scroll en la tabla resulta que el item 4 tambien tiene tiene el cambio de img, tal y como se muestra en la imagen que subi :/

Comment: Es como si el estado del item seleccinado se quedara pegado o algo asi no logro entender esa parte

Comment: Añade dentro de la clase de tu celda el método prepareForReuse y resetea el estado de la imagen del botón.

Comment: grande!!!! muchas gracias :DDD

Comment: Gracias a ti. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

¿ese Protocolo también funcionaría cuando tienes una TableView con secciones?
Yo uso los tag para una única sección y funciona perfectamente pero al añadir secciones me da error “índice fuera de rango”.
¿Alguna solución?

Gracias